# Big file on ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine

Tags: 16.04, du

When I execute `sudo du -h --max-depth=1` I get this result:

[image]

The 13g are taking the whole space of the virtual machine but when I execute `ls -la` the files size total size is only 96k.

I'm not sure about what is happening but the virtual machine can not be used.

Comment: Please clarify what your actual issue is, as everything seems to be normal.

Comment: `ls -la` gives you the total space of the files in the root directory itself (if you have any), plus a couple of K for each directory. The `du` command gives the total space of the files in each directory and below. As @meskobalazs states, there is no contradiction here.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300). Paste the text directly to your question and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 2):

A large amount of space is being used by `/var` which is likely related to log files. For whatever reason, systemd likes to use a lot of disk space storing almost every bit of history made to log files. You can clean it up using:

```
sudo journalctl --vacuum-size=50M
```

This will delete all the old log files leaving just 50MB of logs remaining, which is likely more than enough for most basic logging needs. You can make this a permanent setting by creating/modifying the `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` file and putting:

```
SystemMaxUse=50M
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to find out where the big files are on your system you must tell `du` to sum up the disk usage for every directory.

```
$sudo du -sh /*
13M     /bin
184M    /boot
4,0K    /cdrom
4,0M    /core
4,0K    /dev
41M     /etc
63G     /home
--- snip
```

From here on you better omit the `-h` and instead let the output be sorted by numbers. In my case I would descend into `/home` (the biggest directory).

```
sudo du -s /home/* | sort -n | head -3
```

( `-n` sorts numerically instead of alphabetically, `head -3` only displays the first three entries)

Now I again select the biggest directory and so forth until I find the culprit.

```
$sudo du -s /home/* | sort -nr |head -3  
61121744        /home/g
4306660 /home/andrea
37032   /home/test

$sudo du -s /home/g/* | sort -nr |head -3
10054692        /home/g/temp
8006620 /home/g/Downloads
5056024 /home/g/Documents
```

In case your have "hidden" directories (most likely in a home directory) you additionally use a slightly different command

```
$sudo du -s /home/g/.* | sort -nr |head -3
12754648        /home/g/.vagrant.d
4400684 /home/g/.local
3311584 /home/g/.cache
```